# Recent film in which young male avoids detection of his thoughts by repeating his name and who he is. He searches for crashed spaceship to send SOS

Tags: story-identification, movie

This person may be on an alien planet or dystopian earth. He must repeat his name and who he is in his thoughts to avoid detection by antagonists. I think he meets a girl who survived a spaceship wreck. Together they seek the wreckage in order to send a message to other ships that may be looking for her.
Really cool graphics show internal thought process.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How recent is "recent?"  Last year?  Past 10 years?  Was this movie live-action or animated?  Where did you see it?

Comment: Please use the checklist to ask a good story-identification question. To edit, press the 'edit' button just below the tags 'story-identification' and 'movie'. Link: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: *'Kunta. Kinte.'*

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like 'Chaos Walking'.

It is pretty recent, as in 2021.

> follows a young man who lives in a dystopian world without women, where all living creatures can hear each other's thoughts in streams of images, words and sounds, called "Noise".

This is represented by cool looking graphics on screen: mostly a kind of swirly mist that accompanies the audible thoughts.

> He must repeat his name and who he is in his thoughts to avoid detection by antagonists.

The protagonist does this in a particular scene to avoid the antagonist knowing what he has found.

[image]

> When a woman crash-lands on the planet, he protects her from danger.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Later:

> arrive at the ruins of the first colony ship. They enter it and try to send a signal to the colony ship

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much. This was a really good "low budget" film. I am a writer and I have a different/but similar interaction in a manuscript that I am working on. The "thought" graphics gave me an idea that want to explore. Will send you an update. Thanks again!

Comment: @BobbyJackBlain If this is the movie you were looking for, don't forget to 'Accept' the answer.